# c- Allocate and Free 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sigabrt

I am trying to write 2 functions, one to Dynamic allocation a 2D array,Other to free this 2D array:

```
int allocate(int **array, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof (int));
  }
  /* Code fo fill the array*/
  return 1;
}
void de_allocate(int **v, unsigned int rows) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    free(v[i]);
  }
  free(v);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rows, columns;
    rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    columns = atoi(argv[2]);
    int *ipp[rows];
    allocate(ipp, rows, columns);
    de_allocate(ipp,rows);  
    return 0;
}
```

I must respect the allocate function signature :

```
int allocate(int **array, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns)
```

And at the end of allocate function ipp must have access to allocated 2D array.

Allocate function it's right but in de_allocate function i have a SIGABRT Signal

Comment: This is *not* a 2D array but only an emulation of it. Don't do that such code should be just used in a museum. Use real 2D arrays. If they tend to be big, don't allocated them on the stack and use `int (*ipp)[rows] = malloc(sizeof(double[rows][colums]));` to allocate and `free(ipp)` to free it and the end. No `for` loops necessary. So even your functions wouldn't server much of a purpose any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to free a stack allocated var with code `free(v);`

You could do that if you mallocated the array of pointer, but you declare it locally in `main` function with `int *ipp[rows];`

Change it to `int **ipp = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);` if you want to leave de_allocate as is.

You could test it with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int allocate(int **array, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof (int));
  }

  /* Code fo fill the array*/
  return 1;
}

void de_allocate(int **v, unsigned int rows) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    free(v[i]);
  }
  free(v);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int rows, columns;
    int temp = 0;
    rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    columns = atoi(argv[2]);

    int **ipp = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);

    allocate(ipp, rows, columns);

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            ipp[i][j] = temp++;

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            printf("ipp[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, ipp[i][j]);

    de_allocate(ipp,rows);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void de_allocate(int **v, unsigned int rows) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    free(v[i]);
  }
  free(v);
-----^----
here you are attempting to free a variable for which you didn't dynamically allocate memory in the first place

}
```